# What do you understand by the word WORHT?

Tags: rebus

What do you understand by this word?

> WORHT

Is the word asked correct, or wrong? Or is this a puzzle?

Comment: it's not lateral-thinking; it's a rebus.

Comment: So, Which of the answers is correct??

Comment: @Sid based on the phrasing of the question and the low rep of the poster, I'm going to guess that this was a legitimate "solve this for me, please" question and the correct answer is unknown to the poster.

Comment: If you found the answer to be correct, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 30):

I think it's meant to indicate the single word

> THROWBACK.

Comment: I'd have went with two words, the second ending "wards"

Comment: Thanx...  can you explain?

Comment: This belongs to a class of puzzles where a common word or phrase is indicated punningly and kinda diagrammatically. The puzzle is to work out what the word or phrase is. They often involve elements like OVER, UNDER, BACK, OUT, IN, etc., which for the purpose of the puzzle get applied to other parts of the word-or-phrase. In this case, we've taken THROW and written it BACKwards, to indicate the word THROWBACK (meaning someone or something that seems to belong in an earlier time).

Comment: I was just going through the list of such puzzles on a website and saw this question and also the answer. You beat me first. Nice one.

Comment: Such a puzzle is called a rebus. Have fun on Google images. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be

> "Worth" and some one mistyped it as "Worht"

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. It is a good first try, you could have said "Not Worth" :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> misplaced values

because it's

> the word "worth" with the last two letters placed wrong.